# what is <T> in System.Span<T> in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm new into c# and I see a lot of things like `System.Span<T>`, `System.Memory<T>`, `Span<T>`, `Memory<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` etc. in the C# documentation.

Can somebody please explain what `<T>` is?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Those are called generics:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Generic Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters)

> In a generic type or method definition, a type parameter is a placeholder for a specific type that a client specifies when they create an instance of the generic type. A generic class, such as `GenericList<T>` listed in Introduction to Generics, cannot be used as-is because it is not really a type; it is more like a blueprint for a type. To use `GenericList<T>`, client code must declare and instantiate a constructed type by specifying a type argument inside the angle brackets. The type argument for this particular class **can be any type recognized by the compiler**. Any number of constructed type instances can be created, each one using a different type argument, as follows:

For instance:

```
GenericList<float> list1 = new GenericList<float>();
GenericList<ExampleClass> list2 = new GenericList<ExampleClass>();
GenericList<ExampleStruct> list3 = new GenericList<ExampleStruct>();
```

> In each of these instances of GenericList, every occurrence of T in the class is substituted at run time with the type argument. By means of this substitution, we have created three separate type-safe and efficient objects using a single class definition. For more information on how this substitution is performed by the CLR

In addition to the above, you [can also have constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) about the type that `T` can be.